# getting a stack overflow error and im not really sure as to why

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Edit:

Main method...

creates a new player.

Player class...

creates an instance of hand.

Hand class...

creates an arraylist

thats all. its pretty simple

```
public class Player 
{
/*------------------------
 * instantiating variable
 -----------------------*/
protected Hand hand;
protected boolean active = false;

/*------------
 * constructor
 -----------*/
    public Player()
{
    hand = new Hand();
    hand.setSize(5);
}



public class Hand extends Player
    {
/*-----------------------------------------
 * variable declaration
 ----------------------------------------*/
ArrayList <Card> hand;
protected int size;
Card temp;

     /*------------------------------------------
 * constructor
 * creates arraylist of cards to keep in hand
 ------------------------------------------*/
public Hand()
{
    hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
}

/*-------------------------------
 * sets the size of the max hand
 ------------------------------*/
public void setSize(int newSize)
{
    size = newSize;

}
```

Edit: the error is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at Player.<init>(Player.java:19)

at Hand.<init>(Hand.java:21)
```

line 19 in Player is the "public Player()"

line 21 of Hand is the "public Hand()"

just for reference

Comment: Seems fine. I think your bug is somewhere else

Comment: Edit your question and add the exception you're having

Comment: This doesn't seem to be complete code, is it?

Comment: no its not. if i comment out the player instantiation it runs so im pretty sure it has to do with creating a new player.  I only posted the relevant code.  the first constructor is from the player class and the rest of it is from the hand class. ill post the error

Comment: The relevant code is the one that contains the bug :D

Comment: Providing more code will help you get help :)

Comment: Could you come up with a short but complete example that demonstrates the problem, and post that?

Comment: Perhaps you are calling the Player constructor from the Hand constructor, from which you call the Player constructor again?

Comment: It is not a good idea to have a derived class dependency from a base class. What would happen is that the base class would then have a knowledge of derived class which defeats the purpose of abstraction.

Comment: all that the hand constructor does is make an arraylist... i wish it was that easy.

Comment: You have implicitly creating a recursive code by the contructors calling each other. new Player(explicit call) -> new Hand(explicit call)  -> new Player (implicit because of inheritance) -> new Hand (explicit call). You need to use composition without inheritance.

Comment: The Hand class is extending Player. So that complicates it and you have this problems.

Comment: so basically i have to not make hand extend player?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Hand` extends `Player` and therefore has all of `Player`'s data members, including

```
protected Hand hand;
```

To initialize those inherited members, `Hand`'s constructor implicitly calls `Player`'s.

1. You call `Hand`'s constructor.
2. It calls `Player`'s constructor.
3. `Player`'s constructor executes `new Hand()`, and the cycle repeats indefinitely until you run out of stack space.

Comment: yep that fixed it. didnt even think about that. smh